# When constructing an ECM, is it possible to compare two values?

Tags: templating, elementcriteriamodel, comparisons

My section has two numeric fields, `lorem` and `ipsum`. It's possible for users to enter any integer they want into these two fields.

**I want to grab all results where `lorem` is greater than `ipsum`.**

Here's my starting point...

```
{% set results = craft.entries.section('foo').limit(3) %}
```

How would I alter the above Element Criteria Model to only retrieve entries where the value of `lorem` is greater than the value of `ipsum`?

Comment: Pretty sure you're going to have to get your hands dirty to achieve this. Maybe do a raw query to return all of the record IDs which meet your lorem / ipsum criterion, and then use those IDs in the main ElementCriteriaModel query, so you still get Craft to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: I would say create a variable in a plugin to handle this, have it return the find() call.

Comment: Crazy... I think you guys are right, I'll need to dig into a plugin to make this work. I'm a bit surprised there isn't a simpler solution. Thanks Stephen & SublymeRick!

Comment: @LindseyD, you should post your Slack solution in here. I'm sure this will help some people.

Comment: @LazyPirate I haven't actually tried it yet, so I'm not sure if/how it works. But I'll try to post back when I do!